# HTML templates for web applications

Tags: website-design, web-app, html

There are a lot of sites with free templates for homepages. These are often too simple for web applications, which have sometimes a lot of deeper nested content.

For example. An application view which displays a list of customers. One customer is "expanded" (details are visible). Inside of this details, there is a list of notes. Each note contains action-elements like delete or edit. And even this example is very simple. Sometimes the custormer list needs grouping boxes.

This requires more boxes or more colors, which is very difficult.

Are there any templates for web applications with deeply nested content?

Answer (score 2):

[Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net/) has some admin designs for photoshop that you can play with. They might also have html versions by now too. You would have to pay for these...

If you're looking for an app framework, and not a design framework, cakePHP is a really good php framework.

Answer (score 0):

Templates for marketing sites aren't that great to begin with. I can't imagine a template for an application that would be useful given that immense set of unique variables and unique business and technological requirements of every single web application.

If your goal is to cut down on UI dev time, then I'd consider putting that effort towards a component and/or pattern library. Be it one you build yourself or base on the many publicly shared ones out there. Incorporating frameworks can help as well (CSS frameworks, javascript libraries, Rapid Prototyping code frameworks, etc.)

Comment: I already have components and a framework which works fine. But it looks ugly. I have used too much colors and borders because of the deep nesting. I would like a theme template with deeply nested components which looks good, so I can apply it to my application.

Comment: Alas, I don't think you're going to find a solution in template form. You really need to bring in a graphic/UI designer for this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to combine a web site template with a client-side widget library such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or [Sencha's Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/). These will give you the desired control over displaying complicated interactive controls like "customer lists".

You could possibly get a good business going providing ready-made templates including such controls. Perhaps you should start one based on your request! ;-)